# Transfer IOS App from Testflight of one account to another account

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

App is **not published** on App Store but distributed to testers via **Testflight** on previous account.
Now I have to shift the app to new account.

**With same Bundle Identifier**

- Can I place it on new account with same bundle identifier?
- What will be the procedure to transfer the app because it is in the Testflight and docs says "The app must have a published version." ?
- If I just have to simply upload it to new account then what changes to be made and what are the consequences?
- Will the testers get it as a new app or an update to installed one?
- Are the certificates of older account are required to sign the app?

**With new Bundle Identifier**

- App will be treated as a new app and will be signed with new certificates. So will there be any chances to conflict with the previous one? Or I have to remove the older app from previous account?
- If there is any way to distribute it as an update to previous one that replaces the installed one?
- What changes to be made and what are the consequences?

Answer (score 4):

According to the Apple Doc -

The app must meet specific criteria to be transferable.

App transfer criteria. Before an app can be transferred it has to meet the following criteria:

1. Both accounts can’t be in a pending or changing state, and the latest version of the agreements in the Agreements, Tax, and Banking section must be accepted.
2. No version of the app can use an iCloud entitlement.
3. No version of the app can use a Passbook entitlement.
4. The App must have had at least one version that has been released to the App Store.
5. In-app purchase product IDs on the app can’t be the same as product IDs on any apps in the recipient’s account.
6. TestFlight beta testing should be turned off for all beta versions of the app.
7. Sandboxed Mac apps that share the Application Group Container Directory with other Mac apps cannot be transferred.

Source - [Apple Doc Link](https://support.appmachine.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000012284-Transfer-your-app-to-another-iOS-Developer-Account)

***So ,***

- You can not move your **Testflight** app on your new account.
- Yes, you can place it on new account with same bundle identifier but before that you have to delete that app first from App Store Connect.I believe that is the case, although you probably could rename the original rather than deleting it.
  When an app is removed in this way, the app's name is released to other developers, so make sure you can reuse the name (bundle id),as long as no other developer grabs it before you do.
- *Upload it to new account then what changes to be made* - just upload it as you did before for **Testflight** and there will be no consequences.
- *Will the testers get it as a new app or an update to installed one* - If you upload it as a new app from your new developer account, it will be a fresh new app for the testers ,not a updated version, but if that version contains any changes then definitely they will get it.
- *Are the certificates of older account are required to sign the app* - No. But you have to download the necessary certification to upload an iPA on iTunes connect for your new developer account.

**With new Bundle Identifier**

- No, there will be no conflicts if you upload the app with different developer account with new identifier as long as it's for **Testflight** and not published in app store.
- You can notify the tester about this app, what it's new feature, or easy way to do that is update the version number while uploading it. If is there anything else you have to know then feel free to ask me in the comment, i will be happy to answer that.

Comment: What about the build number? Should I reset it to 1 or continue? Is there any difference?